# Can't find Google API Gem

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

Sorry, I'm new to Ruby so this may be a dumb question to ask, I'm sure I'm missing something.

I'm trying to use a 3rd party library for Google Drive access. When using it, I need to require google/api_client, which I assume is the google-api-client gem (I could be wrong here, and this could be the issue.)

I've tried reinstalling the 3rd party library, and I've tried installing google-api-client using `gem install` and `sudo gem install` commands, but all to no avail.

Anyone know how to get this gem working?

Answer (score 0):

Install the gem like this:

```
gem install google-api-client --pre
```

Then, to use drive api, use:

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2 # Alias the module
drive = Drive::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = authorization # See Googleauth or Signet libraries

# Search for files in Drive (first page only)
files = drive.list_files(q: "title contains 'finances'")
files.items.each do |file|
  puts file.title
end

# Upload a file
metadata = Drive::File.new(title: 'My document')
metadata = drive.insert_file(metadata, upload_source: 'test.txt', content_type: 'text/plain')

# Download a file
drive.get_file(metadata.id, download_dest: '/tmp/myfile.txt')
```

See [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) for more instruction and usage.

Comment: For those curious `--pre` allows installation of prerelease versions. `google-api-client` is currently in alpha status so you have to explicitly want to install the unstable version.